# THREE.js Orthographic camera position not updating after *dolly* with OrbitControl

Tags: three.js

I'm using THREE.OrbitControls to **dolly** a THREE.OrthographicCamera. But, even thought the ortho camera renders correctly as repositioned, all that is updating on the orthographic camera is the 'zoom' property. Even after calling camera.updateProjectionMatrix(). Do I need to manually update the 'position' property of the camera based on the updated 'zoom' property? I want to display its position in my UI after dollying it.

(Note, this is a rewrite of my other question,[THREE.js Orthographic camera position not updating after zoom with OrbitControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55814148/three-js-orthographic-camera-position-not-updating-after-zoom-with-orbitcontrol), in which I thought I was zooming with the OrbitControl but was actually dollying. Sorry about this).

Answer (score 0):

Dollying in/out with an ortho cam would have an unnoticeable effect. With ortho cams there is no perception of proximity because it has no perspective. All objects appear the same in size regardless of distance from the lens because the projection rays are all parallel. The only difference you'd notice is when the objects get clipped because they're past the `near` or `far` plane.

[image]

So, the decision was made that scrolling with `OrbitControls` would change the `zoom` of the camera, narrowing in/out of the center.

If you want to force the camera to move further/closer of its focus point, you could just translate it back/forth in the z-axis with:
`camera.translateZ(distance);` A (-) distance would move it closer, and a (+) distance would move it further from its focus point.

Comment: thank you. What would make sense to display in UI when one is zooming the ortho cam? The zoom level itself, or the near/far planes, or something other than those?

Comment: That's entirely up to you. The near/far planes don't really change though. I guess you could make the viewing frustum narrower. It changes its width & height, but not its length.